# I want to override and need to store the new values in a CSV file

Tags: c#

I am modifying the data in my CSV file according to my requirement and I am able to modify it successfully. But the Previous Data is not getting deleted. How can I do that?

```
 List csvfiles = new List();
        private void btnimport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.CheckFileExists = true;
            openFileDialog.AddExtension = true;
            openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
            openFileDialog.Filter = "CSV files (.csv)|.csv";
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                foreach (string fileName in openFileDialog.FileNames)
                {
                    csvfiles.Add(fileName);
                }
            }
        }
```

`public void csvedit()
    {
        string path = @"C:\Users\Sunil\Videos\original\GSK.csv";
        string csvContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
        Regex r = new Regex(@"("",""(?=[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}))");

        var newStr = r.Replace(csvContent, "\n").Trim("\"".ToArray());
        newStr.Trim("\"".ToArray());
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, newStr);
    }

    private void btnexport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        csvedit();
        string installedPath = "C:\\Users\\Sunil\\Videos\\changed";

        //Check whether folder path is exist
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(installedPath))
        {
            // If not create new folder
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(installedPath);
        }
        //Save pdf files in installedPath ??
        foreach (string sourceFileName in csvfiles)
        {
            string destinationFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(installedPath, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(sourceFileName));
            System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFileName, destinationFileName);
            MessageBox.Show("File Exported Successfully");
        }
    }`

Comment: Try using StreamWriter with 'append' set to false: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_String_System_Boolean_